# How to disconnect a server from LDAP

Tags: fedora, ldap, openldap, nsswitch

I have a Fedora server configured for LDAP. However, the LDAP server is gone, and now I'm unable to SSH into it. I've rebooted the server into single-user mode, brought up eth0 and started sshd, but when I try and ssh into it, the connection times out and the server reports "nss_ldap: could not search LDAP server server is unavailable".

How do I completely purge LDAP from the system and disconnect it from any external LDAP dependency? I've ran `yum remove openldap-servers nss-pam-ldapd` and deleted common ldap conf scripts, but still sshd blocks all connections because it can't validate them against a non-existent LDAP server.

Answer (score 2):

You should remove the ldap conf from ssh conf files `/etc/ssh_config` and `/etc/sshd_config` . Check both files for:-

```
PAMAuthenticationViaKbdInt yes
```

and change it to:-

```
PAMAuthenticationViaKbdInt no
```

And of-course don't forget to restart your services:-

```
service sshd restart
```